# LuaTex parse LaTeX to variable

Tags: luatex

I am currently working on a template to be used by our consultants.
For this I have make a set of functions that automatically generate and calculate certain parts of the report.

And example of the LaTeX that would be written would be:

```
\DataPoint{entry=123,description={Discovered that \textbf{something} is going on}, imporantance={High}}
```

This gets parsed using the `xkeyval` package to become beautiful valid LaTeX.
And now the `luatex` part is kicking in. We want to convert these values to lua variables to we can also store them on disk on build validate them etc etc.

Thus now I have:

```
\directlua{
  local datapoint = {}
  datapoint.entry = "{\DataPointEntry}"
  datapoint.description = "{\DataPointDescription}"
}
```

This works great on the entry. But for the description, as there is additional tex in there  I get stack problems:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
\csuse #1->
           \ifcsname #1\endcsname \csname #1\expandafter \endcsname \fi
l.55 }

 11237 words of node memory still in use:
   62 hlist, 10 vlist, 54 rule, 93 disc, 10 local_par, 1 dir, 2 math, 290 glue,
 78 kern, 29 penalty, 956 glyph, 108 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 108 attribute_lis
t, 1 if_stack, 2 write, 17 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 1:3,2:8,3:1,4:12,5:31,6:1,7:12,8:3,9:3,10:14
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

When I remove the LateX in the description field it works flawlessly.
So how can I make LuaTex parse LaTeX first and then convert it to a Lua Variable?

Thanks this is driving me nuts.

Comment: This is the usual TeX problem of expandable versus non-expandable content. What do you want to store for example when the input contains `\textbf`? The 'raw' LaTeX, the formatting removed, ....?

Comment: I want to store it parsed. Textbf does not modify the text so expanded thus without \textbf{}. But when \today is used that it will show the value of \today.

Comment: I'd be wary of assuming anything about `\today`: it gets abused a lot.

Comment: I am just using \today as an example here. We have things like: ```\newcommand{\stolas}{Stolas Bsc. Senior Researcher}```.
And those are used. ```\today``` not really.

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent uncontrolled expansion of material, which happens when you pass material to `\directlua`. At the same time, if you want to expand 'as far as is safe' then you need to do that separately. Something like

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \protected@edef\@tempa{\DataPointEntry}%
  \protected@edef\@tempb{\DataPointDescription}%
  \directlua{
    local datapoint = {}
    datapoint.entry = "\luaescapestring{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@tempa}}"
    datapoint.description = "\luaescapestring{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@tempb}}"
  }%
\endgroup
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks That should help.
Now I have things to google for

Comment: It worked a lot. Thanks. I hve red up on ```\edef``` etc
The thing I don't understand is why ```\protect \emph``` is still not safely expanded. (even thought I only have ```\emph``` in the text itself.